# Database is cleared after first integration test, .NET

Tags: c#, .net, database, integration-testing

Im trying to build my first integration test in .NET API. But unfortunately it seems that my database is clearing after the first test.

**CustomWebApplicationFactory**

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup : class
    {
        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureServices(services => 
            {
                var dbContextDescriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<DataContext>));

                if(dbContextDescriptor != null) services.Remove(dbContextDescriptor);

                var dbConnectionDescriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(
                    d => d.ServiceType == typeof(DbConnection)
                );

                if(dbConnectionDescriptor != null) services.Remove(dbConnectionDescriptor);

                // Create open SqliteConnection so EF won't automatically close it.
                services.AddSingleton<DbConnection>(container =>
                {
                    var connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
                    connection.Open();

                    return connection;
                });

                services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(
                    (container, options) =>
                    {
                        var connection = container.GetRequiredService<DbConnection>();
                        options.UseSqlite(connection);
                    }
                );
            });

            builder.ConfigureTestServices(services => 
            {
                //services.AddSingleton<ITokenService, TokenService>();
                services.AddSingleton<ILoggerFactory, NullLoggerFactory>();
            });

            builder.UseEnvironment("Development");
        }
    }
```

**HttpClientTest**

```
public abstract class HttpClientTest : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program>> , IDisposable
    {
        
        protected readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
        protected readonly JsonSerializerOptions _serializerOptions;
        protected readonly CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program> _factory;


        public HttpClientTest(CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program> factory)
        {
            _factory = factory;
            _httpClient = factory.CreateClient(
                new WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions { AllowAutoRedirect = false }
            );

            _serializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
            {
                PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
            };

#pragma warning disable CS4014
            SetupTestData();
#pragma warning restore CS4014
        }

        private async Task SetupTestData()
        {
            using var scope = _factory.Services.CreateScope();
            var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
            var db = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();

            await Utilities.InitializeDbForTests(db);
        }

        protected async Task<string> AcquireToken()
        {
            var d = new LoginDto { Email = "jan@example.com", Password = "Pa$$w0rd" };
            var content = JsonSerializer.Serialize(d);

            var result = await DoPost("/api/patients/account/login", content);
            Assert.True(result.IsSuccessStatusCode);
            Assert.Equal("application/json", result.Content.Headers.ContentType!.MediaType);

            var resultJson = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var resultObj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<PatientDto>(resultJson, _serializerOptions);

            Assert.NotNull(resultObj);
            Assert.NotNull(resultObj.Token);

            return resultObj.Token;
        }

        protected async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DoGet(string url)
        {
            return await _httpClient.GetAsync(url); //.ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        protected async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DoGetAuthenticated(string url, string token)
        {
            var client = _factory.CreateClient();

            if (token != null)
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                    new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            }

            
            var result = await client.GetAsync(url); //ConfigureAwait(false);
            return result;
        }

        protected async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DoPostAuthenticated(
            string url,
            string token,
            string content
        )
        {
            var client = _factory.CreateClient();

            if (token != null)
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                    new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            }

            return await client
                .PostAsync(url, new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        protected async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DoPost(string url, string content)
        {
            return await _httpClient
                .PostAsync(url, new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        protected async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DoPutAuthenticated(string url, string token, string content)
        {
            var client = _factory.CreateClient();
            if (token != null)
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                    new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            }
            return await client
                .PutAsync(url, new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
```

**Tests**

```
public class PatientsControllerIntegrationTests : HttpClientTest
    {
        public PatientsControllerIntegrationTests(CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program> factory) : base(factory)
        {
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task login()
        {
            var d = new LoginDto { Email = "jan@example.com", Password = "Pa$$w0rd" };
            var content = JsonSerializer.Serialize(d);

            var result = await DoPost("/api/patients/account/login", content);
            Assert.True(result.IsSuccessStatusCode);
            Assert.Equal("application/json", result.Content.Headers.ContentType!.MediaType);
        }


        [Fact]
        public async Task CreateNote()
        {
            var n = new NoteDto{Description = "Test", Value = 1};
            var content = JsonSerializer.Serialize(n);
            var token = await AcquireToken();

            var result = await DoPostAuthenticated("/api/notes/1", token, content);
            Assert.True(result.IsSuccessStatusCode);
        }
    }
```

The error I get after trying to run the tests

```
Assert.True() Failure
Expected: True
Actual:   False
  Ślad stosu:
     at APITests.HttpClientTest.AcquireToken() in C:\Users\karol\Desktop\praca inż\APITests\HttpClientTest.cs:line 50
   at APITests.PatientsControllerIntegrationTests.CreateNote() in C:\Users\karol\Desktop\praca inż\APITests\PatientsControllerIntegrationTests.cs:line 40
```

I thought that using iclassfixture would be adequate. Initially I have one user in my database and after the login test it looks like it disapear.

Comment: Are you using `AttachDbFilename` in the connection string?

Comment: @Charlieface no I`m not

Comment: Just realized you are using SQLite `DataSource=:memory:` doesn't that mean it gets wiped when you close the connection?

Comment: I thnik yes, but thats why I used IClassFixture